# Understanding Ruby Class: "undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass"

Tags: ruby, methods, quicksort

I'm following a class on Coursera and I'm trying to implement the quicksort algorithm in Ruby. I'm very new to the language and the concepts of OOP.

I've created two functions: one which is the quickSort function which calls the partition routine (that splits the array into two subarrays according to the pivot which is the first element of the array).

Eventually I'll put these two methods under a class Array, but for now I figured this would be OK.

I tried running this on an array (a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]), but I run into the following error:

```
A2.rb:16:in `partition': undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
    from A2.rb:15:in `each'
    from A2.rb:15:in `partition'
    from A2.rb:33:in `quickSort'
```

Here's my code:

```
    def partition(array, left_idx, right_idx)
      num_comp = array.length - 1
      p = array[left_idx]
      i = left_idx + 1
      j = left_idx + 1
      puts "#{left_idx}, #{right_idx}, #{array[j]} #{j}"
      puts "pivot = #{p}"
      for j in (left_idx + 1..right_idx)
        if (left_idx < j < right_idx and left_idx < i < right_idx)
          if (array[j] > p)
            j = j + 1
          else 
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
          end
        end
      end
      #swap pivot and rightmost value in subarray that contains < p
      array[1], array[i] = array[i], array[1]
      pivot_idx = i
      return array, num_comp, pivot_idx
    end

    def quickSort(array, start_idx, end_idx)
      array_n, num_comp, pivot_idx = partition(array, start_idx, end_idx)
      left_array = array_n[start_idx..pivot_idx - 1]
      right_array = array_n[pivot_idx + 1..end_idx]
      if (left_array.length > 1) 
        array_n = quickSort(array_n, start_idx, pivot_idx - 1)
      end
      if (right_array.length > 1)
        array_n = quickSort(array_n, pivot_idx + 1, end_idx)
      end
      return array
    end

    #a = Array.new()
    a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    quickSort(a, 0, 4)
    print "Array"
    puts a
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
left_idx < j < right_idx
```

You can't do this.

left_idx < j is resolving first to "True"

and then the expression becomes true < right_idx and < is an invalid operator..

Change the expresison to if left_idx < j && j < right_idx

Comment: Got it. I was hoping that I could combine two conditionals together and for some reason I thought it was possible. I forget where I picked this syntax up (perhaps it was in MATLAB).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this:

```
left_idx < j < right_idx and left_idx < i < right_idx
```

You need to build up the conditional:

```
((j > left_idx) && (j < left_idx)) && (etc)
```

Comment: maybe `j.between?(left_idx+1, right_idx-1) && i.between?(left_idx+1, right_idx-1)`

Comment: or `((left_idx-1)...right_idx).include?(j) && ((left_idx-1)...right_idx).include?(i)`

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu As in the other answers--yes, I saw them. I don't find them much, if any, more readable, but YMMV.

Comment: Yea, I thought I could combine the two. The confusing part was trying to understand the error. What does it mean that there's an undefined method '<' for the true class? I don't think I have any instantions in my code. Perhaps this is something specific to Ruby that I'm not following?

Comment: @SammyLee It means you're trying to apply `<`, ultimately a method, to the result of a comparison. Comparisons give you a boolean instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (left_idx < j < right_idx and left_idx < i < right_idx)
```

This is valid math, but invalid Ruby (and invalid in most other programming languages as well).  What you want instead is:

```
if (left_idx < j and j < right_idx and left_idx < i and i < right_idx)
```

What is happening is that Ruby interprets "<" as a method.  Therefore, the original line becomes:

```
if ((left_idx.<(j)).<(right_idx)) and ((left_idx.<(i)).<(right_idx))
```

In your case, the result of (left_idx.<(j)) is "true".  So it then tries to call < on the "true" class, and it doesn't exist, resulting in the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
(left_idx < j < right_idx and left_idx < i < right_idx)
```

`left < middle < right` may be what people usually write in math, but in Ruby, `<` is nothing special - it's just a method. Specifically, a method returning a boolean value. The result of `left_idx < j` is always either true or false, and then you're trying to compare `right_idx` to that value. Obviously, that doesn't make any sense.

You could write that line as

```
left_idx < j && j < right_idx #...
```

or

```
(left_idx..right_idx).include? j && (left_idx..right_idx).include? i
```

or

```
([i,j].all? {|v| (left_idx..right_idx).include? v})
```

A somewhat more idiomatic way to write quicksort would be

```
def quicksort(arr)
   pivot, *rest = arr
   left,right = rest.partition{|v| v<pivot}.map{|a| if !a.empty? then quicksort(a) else a end}
   left.push(pivot) + right
end
```

This can probably be still done nicer. Note that this isn't in-place quicksort, but yours didn't seem to be either.